# Value is not updating in MaterialTable

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I try to edit the value and update the same but its not updating in MaterialTable
Below is the link which am refering
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable
under this am refering Cell Editable Example

what am missing here

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
import React from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

export default function CellEditable() {
  const { useState } = React;

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { title: "Name", field: "name" },
    {
      title: "Surname",
      field: "surname",
      initialEditValue: "initial edit value"
    },
    { title: "Birth Year", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
    {
      title: "Birth Place",
      field: "birthCity",
      lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
    }
  ]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
    { name: "Zerya Betül", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 }
  ]);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Cell Editable Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("newValue: " + newValue);
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using never sets the state, it just logs to the console.

You need to set the state at some point. I was able to get this working, though I am uncertain if this is the correct approach.

**Update**

If you wish to disable a specific column you can add `editable: 'never'` to the specific column. See below where I added this to the `birthYear`.

```js
function CellEditable() {
  const { useState } = React;

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname', initialEditValue: 'initial edit value' },
    { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric', editable: 'never' },
    {
      title: 'Birth Place',
      field: 'birthCity',
      lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
    },
  ]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
    { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 },
  ]);

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Cell Editable Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const clonedData = [ ...data ]
            clonedData[rowData.tableData.id][columnDef.field] = newValue
            setData(clonedData)
            
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: is it possible to restrict any specific column to not editable, in the existing MaterialTable, I tried passing editable: false in the columns array, it was not working, is it supportable

Comment: @chidanandaMN you can add `editable: 'never'` to the column. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Nitsew, cant find 'tableData', rowData is just mapping all of the fields, also columnDef.field is becoming undefined, cannot be used as index